# the data do not contain the naming of columns, how can i add it in using a manual Python list?

Tags: python, pandas

i try to concatenate my all_train_data with my_columns_name, since my all_train_data doesnt have any columns name

```
columns_name = ["Popularity", "Check-in", "Activities", "Category"] \
            + ["F_{:d}".format(i) for i in range(1, 26)] \
            + ["CC{:d}".format(i) for i in range(1, 6)] \
            + ["Base time", "Post length", "Post count", "Post promotion", "Span time"] \
            + ["Post_date_{:d}".format(i) for i in range(1, 8)] \
            + ["Base_date_{:d}".format(i) for i in range(1, 8)] \
            + ["Span count"]
all_train_data = [pandas.read_csv("Dataset/Training/Features_Variant_{:d}.csv".format(d), header=None) for d in range(1, 6)]
# concatenate training data here
train_data = all_train_data
train_data.columns = columns_name

train_data["bias"] = 1

train_data.head()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `names` argument to `pandas.read_csv()`

```
all_train_data = pandas.read_csv("Dataset/Training/Features_Variant_{:d}.csv".format(d), header=None, names=columns_name) for d in range(1, 6)
```

And the call to `pandas.read_csv()` shouldn't be inside `[]`, that wraps the dataframe in a list.

Comment: so i dont have to use line `train_data.columns = columns_name`

Comment: i used names argument but then i got _TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str_ from the line `train_data["bias"] = 1`

Comment: Remove the `[]` around the call to `pandas.read_csv()`. I updated the answer.